# mass transit exceptions : redelivery not working

Tags: asp.net-core, masstransit

I want to use mass transit redelivery for some exception .
according to mass transit [document](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#retry) this must be worked :

consumer class :

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<SendEmailEvent> context)
{
         try
            {
                ...
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"email not sent to {email} errors : {ex.Message}", ex);
            }
}
```

start up class :

```
 Uri schedulerEndpoint = new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/quartz");

services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
                x.AddConsumer<EmailConsumer>();

                x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.UseHealthCheck(provider);

                    cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("guest");
                        h.Password("guest");
                    });

                    cfg.UseMessageScheduler(schedulerEndpoint);

                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("EmailQueue", ep =>
                    {
                        ep.UseScheduledRedelivery(r => r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)));
                        ep.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Immediate(5));
                        ep.ConfigureConsumer<EmailConsumer>(provider);
                    });
                }));
});

services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

after 5 Immediate failed attempted (I change consumer implementation to catch error every time) it won't send any request after 2 or 3 mins (Intervals config time) also it does not create 'quartz' Queue .

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Have you [setup Quartz as a scheduler](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/scheduling/), typically it runs as a separate service but can also be run within the same process to schedule messages.